# R - Define several step function for lapply

Tags: r, function, lapply

Hi I have a list SPX400

I have already used lapply to subset: `SPX400<- lapply(ALL400, function(x) x[x$ticker=="SPX",])`

However I now want to filter my dataset even more and have tried to set up the following, defining a function to be used by lapply:

```
    Usedfilter <- function(x) {
  mutate(fifteen = x[x$expirDate-x$trade_date-15]) %>% #making new vairable
  filter(fifteen >=0) %>% # filter on fifteen
  mutate(Stockandexpricedif = x[x$stkPx-x$strike]) %>% #making new variable
  filter(Stockandexpricedif < 10 & Stockandexpricedif > -10) # filter on Stockandexpricedif
}

SPXfilter <- lapply(SPX400, Usedfilter)
```

I get the following error:

```
 Error in is.data.frame(.data) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

Hope you can help me out.

This is the structure of SPX400:

```
$ : tibble [2,498 × 37] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ ticker          : chr [1:2498] "SPX" "SPX" "SPX" "SPX" ...
  ..$ stkPx           : num [1:2498] 1923 1923 1923 1923 1923 ...
  ..$ expirDate       : Date[1:2498], format: "2014-08-01" "2014-08-01" "2014-08-01" "2014-08-01" ...
  ..$ yte             : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ strike          : num [1:2498] 1350 1375 1400 1425 1450 ...
  ..$ cVolu           : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ cOi             : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 30 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ pVolu           : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ pOi             : num [1:2498] 770 3573 2246 7984 20967 ...
  ..$ cBidPx          : num [1:2498] 569 544 519 494 469 ...
  ..$ cValue          : num [1:2498] 574 549 524 499 474 ...
  ..$ cAskPx          : num [1:2498] 581 556 531 506 481 ...
  ..$ pBidPx          : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ pValue          : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ pAskPx          : num [1:2498] 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 ...
  ..$ cBidIv          : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ cMidIv          : num [1:2498] 0.00542 0.00567 0.00567 0 0.00567 0.00564 0.00567 0.00567 0.00567 0.00567 ...
  ..$ cAskIv          : num [1:2498] 0.0108 0.0113 0.0113 0 0.0113 ...
  ..$ smoothSmvVol    : num [1:2498] 0.321 0.327 0.333 0.333 0.235 ...
  ..$ pBidIv          : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ pMidIv          : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ pAskIv          : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ iRate           : num [1:2498] 1e-04 1e-04 1e-04 1e-04 1e-04 1e-04 1e-04 1e-04 1e-04 1e-04 ...
  ..$ divRate         : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ residualRateData: num [1:2498] -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 ...
  ..$ delta           : num [1:2498] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ gamma           : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ theta           : num [1:2498] -138 -141 -143 -146 -148 ...
  ..$ vega            : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ rho             : num [1:2498] 0.000257 0.000261 0.000266 0.000271 0.000276 ...
  ..$ phi             : num [1:2498] -0.000366 -0.000366 -0.000366 -0.000366 -0.000366 ...
  ..$ driftlessTheta  : num [1:2498] -0.000975 -0.000993 -0.001011 -0.00103 -0.001047 ...
  ..$ extVol          : num [1:2498] 0.102 0.102 0.271 0.271 0.102 ...
  ..$ extCTheo        : num [1:2498] 593 568 543 518 493 ...
  ..$ extPTheo        : num [1:2498] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ spot_px         : logi [1:2498] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ trade_date      : Date[1:2498], format: "2014-08-01" "2014-08-01" "2014-08-01" "2014-08-01" ...
  ..- attr(*, "problems")= tibble [9,071 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. ..$ row     : int [1:9071] 39322 39323 39324 39325 39326 39327 39328 39329 39330 39331 ...
  .. ..$ col     : chr [1:9071] "spot_px" "spot_px" "spot_px" "spot_px" ...
  .. ..$ expected: chr [1:9071] "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE" "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE" "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE" "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE" ...
  .. ..$ actual  : chr [1:9071] "68.38" "68.38" "68.38" "68.38" ...
  .. ..$ file    : chr [1:9071] "'OSMV-20140801.csv'" "'OSMV-20140801.csv'" "'OSMV-20140801.csv'" "'OSMV-20140801.csv'" ...
```

Comment: Can you add data using `dput(SPX400)` ?

Comment: The data is really big. I've tried to access just one of the lists using `SPX400[[1]]` however that just returns NULL.

Comment: I have now tried to make the dates as factors, to see if that would help:`SPXfacor <- lapply(SPX400, function(x) x[as.factor(SPX400$expirDate)])`

`SPXfactor <- lapply(SPXdataframe, function(x) x[as.factor(SPX400$trade_date)])` Now I get the following error: `Error in mutate(., fifteen = x[x$expirDate - x$trade_date - 15]) : 
  is.data.frame(.data) || is.list(.data) || is.environment(.data) is not TRUE `

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? which rows do you want to select and which you want to ignore in each list?

Comment: I want to filter my data so I have certain differences between expiration dates and current dates and also between stkPx price and strike price. I have added the structure of one of the dates in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your datasets are *"big"*, I recommend you to use `data.table`. The solution below is untested.

First, convert all your tables to `data.table` format:

```r
library(data.table)
lapply(SPX400, setDT)
```

Then, define a generic function

```r
Usedfilter <- function(df){
    df2 <- data.table::copy(df)
    df2[,fifteen := get('expirDate') - get('trade_date') - 15]
    df2 <- df[get('fifteen') > 0]
    df2[, ('Stockandexpricedif')  := get('stkPx') - get('strike')]
    #return(
    #  df2[between(get('Stockandexpricedif') , -10, 10, incbounds=FALSE)]
    #)
    return(df2[which.min(fifteen)])
}
```

And then, apply on all your dataframes:

```r
SPX400_filtered <- lapply(SPX400, Usedfilter)
```

Comment: Great answer. However, when I try to use your code I get: `Error in .checkTypos(e, names_x) : Object 'expirDate' not found amongst ` The error is on the last step, trying to create SPX_400 filtered

Comment: First possibility, a problem of standard vs non-standard evaluation. I changed the function to propose standard evaluation. Does it solve the problem ?

Comment: No, still the same issue

Comment: When looking at the structure`str(SPX400)` I get: `List of 400
 $ :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> `

Comment: It's the `SPX400<- lapply(ALL400, function(x) x[x$ticker=="SPX",])` step that creates empty lists. You initally have a dataframe, why to you use `lapply` with filter?

Comment: I thought I needed to do it that way as ALL400 is a list  `typeof(ALL400)
[1] "list"`

Comment: What is weird is that `SPX400` is a dataframe (`tbl_df`). You can try directly `Usedfilter(SPX400)` to see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, before trying `Usedfilter`, you should run `setDT(SPX400)` to convert to data.table

Comment: SPX400 is also a list: `typeof(SPX400)
[1] "list"` a list of 400 dates. I need to make the filters for each of the dates. So that's why I probably would need to run it as lapply. Could it be something to due with the fact that expirDate and trade_date are date formats?

Comment: Yes, it can be. Maybe the difference between them is not interpreted as days

Comment: As I do need fifteen as a variable I have tried to use your code above which seems to work, however I am not able to minimize fifteen: `Usedfilter <- function(x){
  df2 <- x[, fifteen := expirDate - trade_date-15]
  return(df2[(fifteen > 0)])
  df2[, Stockandexpricedif  := stkPx - strike]
  return(
    df2[between(Stockandexpricedif , -10, 10, incbounds=FALSE)]
  )
  df2[which.min(x$fifteen), ] #This step does not work
  }`

Comment: It seems you use several times `return` in the above code, only the first is evaluated. I edited the answer, to show you how to return the line with minimum `fifteen` instead of the previous return.

Comment: Ah okay. So asI still need stockandexpricedif I have to run that in a different function?

Comment: If you want several return, your function should output a list. e.g. `list(df2[between(get('Stockandexpricedif') , -10, 10, incbounds=FALSE)], df2[which.min(fifteen)])`. Depend of what you want to return from the function. In your initial question, you wanted to return your dataframe with a new column (`Stockandexpricedif`) for the rows between -10 and 10. The return was doing that job.

Comment: Okay. Yes I wanted to create both fifteen and stockandexpricedif. I will just create the which.min(fifteen) separately then.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
new_data <- Filter(length, SPX400)

SPXfilter <- lapply(new_data, function(df) subset(df, 
                  abs(expirDate - trade_date) >= 15 & abs(stkPx - strike) < 10))
```

This selects rows where the absolute difference between `expirDate` and `trade_date` is greater than equal to 15 days and absolute difference between `stkPx` and `strike` is less than 10.

Comment: It's the same issue as the suggestion from @linog. I get the error: `Error in subset.default(df, abs(expirDate - trade_date) >= 15 & abs(stkPx -  : 
  object 'expirDate' not found`

Comment: To look at the structure str, I need to set list.len above 200 which is the length of the dataset, does that have anything to say? eg. `str(SPX400, list.len = 200)` returns NULL for all the data frames, but `str(SPX400, list.len = 400)` returns a list of structures for each dataframe in the lists.

Comment: Can you try updated answer? I think there are some empty lists which needs to be removed first.

Comment: I think you are right. It seems like the data is in 201:400 so the first 200 lists should be removed.